# Two versions of PHP - Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, mongodb, php

I have somehow got 2 versions of php installed on my machine (Mac OSx 10.8.3 Mountain Lion). The locations of the 2 versions are -

1. /opt/local/bin  (version 5.3.26)
2. /usr/bin        (version 5.3.14)

Right now, 'php -v' in the terminal returns, 5.3.26 but a simple php test page with the following code

```
phpinfo();
```

return 5.3.15.

Because of this mix-up i cant get php to load the mongodb extension. I'd want to work with version 5.3.26.

How do i get Apache to load this version of php ?

Comment: How are you using PHP in Apache? If you're using mod_php (the Apache module) you probably have to install the mod_php of version 5.3.26. If you are using CGI/FCGI or similar you have to change the Apache configuration or FCGI-script so that it uses the correct path to the 5.3.26 installation.

Comment: Look at your Apache's httpd.conf file to see which PHP version it points to.

Comment: After looking at the httpd.conf file all i could find was this

`LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`

so do i edit the libphp5.so file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Apache is including libphp5.so of the wrong/the *other* installation.

Option 1:

See if you can find a libphp5.so file for your *other* PHP installation and point the Apache config to it (just put the whole path in the `LoadModule` line and restart Apache). If you cannot find such a file, the Apache module wasn't compiled for that PHP version. Compiling that may be a bit complicated, so in that case:

Option 2:

Figure out which PHP you're executing on the command line using `which php` and then just use the *other* one using the full path, e.g. instead of `$ php ...` use `$ /usr/bin/php ...`. Note that you may still have different PHP configuration files for Apache and the CLI.